# system of three linear equations with some artifice

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, systems-of-equations

It is a basic system of equations, but I had never seen it this way, I have applied known resolution methods but I don't see how to get to what they are asking for, can you help me?

says:
By solving the following system of equations with three variables x,y,z

$$-2x +3y +3z=a$$
$$ x-4y -2z=b$$
$$ 5x -y -3z=c$$

it was obtained that
$$xm=16$$
$$yn=48$$
$$zr=64$$

Calculate a+b+c

I come to the following solutions

$$x = (5 a + 3 b + 3 c)/8$$
$$y=(-7 a - 9 b - c)/16$$
$$z=(19 a + 13 b + 5 c)/16$$

but I get there, I don't know how to continue

Comment: $a+b+c = (-2x+3y+3z)+(x-4y-2z)+(5x-y-3z) = 4x-2y-2z$.  That should be good enough if we didn't care what variables we write the answer in.  If we wanted to, we could further rewrite this in terms of $m,n,z$ as $4\left(\frac{16}{m} \right)- 2\left(\frac{48}{n}\right)-2\left(\frac{64}{r}\right)$.  Beyond that, I see no hope to narrowing this down further with the given information.

Comment: Perhaps it is assumed that $x, y, z, m, n, r$ are integers?

Comment: @Gribouillis, hi ,if we assume that x,y,z,m,n,r they are integers, do you have any idea?

Comment: @ JMoravitz, hi , I tried similar ideas, but I had not seen a problem like this before, it will have some hidden artifice